# Getting xmlhttprequest to work from javascript inside qml document

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, qml

So i wrote this qml app for mobile in which i am trying to pass some data via http POST request to a php page on a webserver. After having done some research, I am assured that I should be able to do this from a qml document using javascript xmlhttprequest. all seems very neat and simple (I found a few variations on the web like this [Https POST / GET with Qml/Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790609/https-post-get-with-qml-qt)). From which I used the script in the answer.

For a test scenario, I have spun up a LAMP (with L = Ubuntu server) on a Virtualbox, I try to POST some data in a param (much like in above link) to a .php page but get only http.status = 0 . The php script is never getting any content in $_POST. So first thing to check is that i can actualy do a http POST request to that same server via a webform in a browser. That works without a hitch.

So i am begining to get the idea that doing xmlhttprequest outside of a browser is not the same as within one. And this may mean that i need to do some config voodoo on the Apache side. I am by no means an apache guru So I am at a loss now.

Hopefully someone has done something like this or is spotting what I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Wireshark to check if the data your QML program is sending the same data as your browser test?

Comment: Not yet. I have to add that the weird thing is that i only get http 0 status when pointing the url to the actual page that should handle the POST. If I for example add a wrong port number or point to a non existing page on that server, then i get the expected 404. So it seems that its not like the app can't reach the server at all. So given that, Wireshark wasn't my first line of thought.

Answer (score 0):

oh my :( I made the most idiotic php scripting error that I overlooked about 200 times. Sorry! well lets say that even geniuses err sometimes.

To make this somewhat usefull: I have to say that I still do not understand why I was handed back http.status = 0 . I discovered that this was the wrong errorcode when I started using curl. doing a POST from curl suddenly gave me back general http errorcode 500. So that made me dive into /var/log/apache2/error.log and there I saw my stupid mistake.