# How to send file using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, qml, qt5, qtquick2

How to send file in QML. I tried something like:

```
var pathImage = "file:assets-library:/asset/asset.JPG%3Fid=0EEAFD08-5878-45D1-9045-025FD5CAB907&ext=JPG"
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var request_url = API_URL + '?method=postImage';
request.open('POST', request_url);
var params = "image=" + pathImage;
request.send(params);
```

But it doesn't send file.
How to send file in QML without C-code?

Comment: What are your steps to resolve the issue?

Comment: Did you searched a bit? There's [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8790609/2538363) or [this thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/44629-Using-XMLHttpRequest-for-HTTPS-Post-to-server-with-SSL-certificate). Can that discussions help? :)